# jQuery UI Autocomplete turning off after Rails 3.2 returns form validation errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Rails 3.2 with jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI and am having trouble getting consistent behavior out of the autocomplete functionality. If I have a form with autocomplete and submit it with invalid information so that I get the same form rendered again with a listing of errors, autocomplete turns off.

#### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min
//= require_tree .
```

#### application.html.erb (header only)

```
<head id="work" >
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=device-height">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
```

#### estimates.js.coffee

```
$(document).on 'pageinit', ->
  $('#estimate_client_company').autocomplete source:
    $('#estimate_client_company').data('autocomplete-source')
```

#### estimates_controller.rb

```
class EstimatesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :index]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @estimate = current_user.estimates.build
    @clients = Client.all.sort { |x,y| x[:company].downcase <=> y[:company].downcase }
  end

  def create
    @estimate = current_user.estimates.build(params[:estimate])
    if @estimate.save
      flash[:success] = "Estimate Started!"
      redirect_to @estimate
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

#### new.tml.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Cost Estimate') %>
<% provide(:fback, estimates_path) %>

<%= form_for(@estimate) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'estimates/estimate_form', :f => f %>

  <%= f.submit "Create new Cost Estimate", "data-ajax" => "false",
               "data-role" => "button", "data-theme" =>"b" %>
<% end %>
```

#### _estimate_form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<div class="form-body">
  <%= f.label "Company" %>
  <%= f.text_field :client_company, data: {autocomplete_source: Client.order(:company).map(&:company)},
       "data-ajax" => "false", required: true %>

  <%= f.label :project_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :project_name, required: true %>

  <%= f.label :item_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :item_number, required: true %>
</div>
```

#### _error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="alert_error">
      <div class="alert">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
      </div>
      <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

## EDIT

I have also tried the following with the exact same results:

#### estimates.js.coffee

```
$(document).on 'focus', '#estimate_client_company', ->
  $('#estimate_client_company').autocomplete source:
    $('#estimate_client_company').data('autocomplete-source')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an ID to the HTML element in my application.html.erb and modifying the javascript to use that as root.

#### application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id='hey_grrl_hey' >
   .......
</html>
```

#### estimates.js.coffee

```
$('#hey_grrl_hey').on 'focus', '#estimate_client_company', ->
  $('#estimate_client_company').autocomplete source:
    $('#estimate_client_company').data('autocomplete-source'
```

## EDIT

Attempting to use another element as root (by adding and referencing its ID) totally breaks autocomplete functionality. I've tried using the `body` element and the `<div data-role="page">` element.